# In Word, when typing, let cursor skip a page

Tags: microsoft-word

I am currently in the midst of preparing a thesis, and in Microsoft Word (I am using version 14.7.2 of 2011 and I am a Mac OSX user!) I would like to have pages of figures and tables stand next to the descriptive parts of the text, where I explain what is going on in the figures/tables figures by means of continuous texts and notes. In this way, I want to prevent that images jump around in the text, or prevent to have them sloppily inserted by means of text boxes etc.

[Here is an image imitating what I want to achieve!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTtGN.png)

In effect, however, this also means that I would like the page with the figures and tables to be a steady, immobile page, and that when I edit the "text sections", so to speak, my cursor moves by skipping over a page and leaves that particular page of figures and tables unharmed and isolated. In a sense, I want it to be a separate section, and create a pipeline between two pages at a different position.

e.g. something like this:

```
———  page 7 ("Here I am stopping my sentence at [...]")

————————  page 8 (figures and tables)

———  page 9 ("[...] the end of the page and it continues here")
```

I guess a work-around would be to add figures and tables only when the document is finished (e.g. insert objects once everything is done? They have to appear in my list of figures in the beginning of my document, though, so they need to be part of the document structure and numbered by page!), but this would be a hassle.

What's the smartest way of going about this, perhaps by using sections or tables, for instance, or subdocuments? I'd appreciate any feedback! Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: I don't get what your problem is. You won't be able to just scroll through the text and magically skip the page. To have the page always on its own just add a hard page break in front of it and at the end of it?

Comment: Hi Seth, yes, but inserting a page break would mean that there is no natural continuation of the text like exemplified in the code box above, right? If I were editing the text later, the page break would probably start sliding.

Comment: So you always want to have those figures and tables on page 8 regardless of what happens to your surrounding text?

Comment: Yes, indeed! I always want them there, and I would also like the descriptions for the figures and tables to stay there and not jump anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

For the objects that you want stationary, meaning not moving with text, you first make sure that their current format is set for wrapping text. In Mac Word 2011 if the object is a picture, right click (a.k.a. Control + Click) and choose Format Picture. If it is a Table, right click and choose Table Properties.

On the table properties dialog there is a Positioning button, click it and then remove the tic mark on the box that is labeled Move With Text. For Pictures and other shape objects on the Format dialog is an Advanced button. Click it and remove the tic mark on Move Object with Text and place a tic on the Lock Anchor.

Comment: Hi Rich, thank you very much for this response. In a sense this can indeed solve a few things, but I was wondering if there is a way to "lock anchor" for the entire page, meaning that also the descriptions for the figures and tables stay right where they are on the page.

Comment: You could put the table description in a final row of the table and then it is locked with the table.